# Why is my iOS5 Core Data project complaining about needing iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios5

My project appears to be for iOS 5 and newer but my build is resulting in the error: "to-many relationship Blah.comments option requires iOS 5.0 or later".

I am using the ordered to-many relationship & binary external storage, which indeed are iOS 5 only.

I've set my Target's iOS Development Target to "iOS 5.0", the project's iOS Development Target (in the Deployment target section) to "5.0", and I'm using the default Base SDK of "Latest iOS (5.1)".

Is there a setting I'm missing in Xcode to preclude building for iOS 4 or am I doing something else wrong? I am using Xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002) and I'm used to targeting as far back as possible instead of the latest and greatest.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? happening to me now...

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when copying a xcdatamodel file from a new ios7 project to an older project using Xcode 5 dp-6. 
The way I finally worked around it was by opening the older project in the older xcode, compiling, and then opening again in xcode 5. 
Now everything compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 5 atm, but is your xcdatamodeld file set to iOS 5 or less?

Its located here in the "utilities" bar under the "file inspector"

[image]

Comment: Also working in xcode 5, checked in the older version of xcode and it works fine.